# Two UILabels like UITableViewCellRightDetail using UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I have a Horizontal `UIStackView` with two `UILabel`s. I need it to be styled like `UITableViewCellRightDetail`.

The first Label (on the left) should have more priority in resizing.

Here is the example:

[image]

I need it to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just use right alignement for the second label to achieve the desired appearance on your second image.

However this will not affect size of the labels. If you want first label to fit as much as it can, you can define a width constraint and set it manually from code after you [calculate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits) it. The second label will just have leading and trailing constraints.